# Autodesk Model Derivative obj output

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I used model derivative API on revit model to download its components separately. I got output file in obj format which is just code. But if I want to use that component in revit, How to do it? How to download that code and how to transfer it to revit format? [Attaching screenshot of obj file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZcf2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OBJ file is geometry only. The code you show represents that geometry. All Revit buiding information is lost when converting from Revit to OBJ.

You can easily bring the OBJ back into Revit again by parsing the geometry definition and creating a DirectShape from it. That is demonstrated by the open source `DirectObjLoader` programming sample:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/DirectObjLoader

You can also purchase this functionality from the Autodesk Exchange AppStore, if you are not interested in adapting the open source version yourself for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to convert the revit file into obj then back to revit?
You can download the original file by using the GET object method here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/